# How to ask user input to call a method

Tags: java, calculator

I want to make a simple calculator, so one that will calculate square meter, one that will calculate "pi" or anything you can imagine. But i want to call on the beginning of the running program, the calculator i want to use. so if i run the program, that the system will ask me if i want to use the calculator that calculates square meter or the pi.  for example output:

1. **which calculator you want to use:** SquareMeter
2. **enter first number:** 2
3. **enter second number:** 4
4. **your answer is:** 8

My question is, how do i make this?

Comment: Have you tried googling for "reading from the console in Java"? If not, then do it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask].  There are plenty of online java tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I can think of, the first is rather complicated but deals with a wide variety of potential user input, the second is simple using basic programming concepts but is limited in what it can do.

Use any of the methods described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string). (I'm new. If referring to other answers like this is against the rules, just let me know, and please don't hate.)

Example code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class StackTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Method method = null;
        // set methodName equal to the name of the method to be called
        String methodName = "hi";
        StackTester cls = new StackTester();
        Class c = cls.getClass();
        try {
            method = c.getMethod(methodName, int.class);
            System.out.println("method = " + method.toString()); 
        } 
        catch (SecurityException e) {
            System.out.println("fail1");
        } 
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.println("fail2");
        }
        try {
              System.out.println(method.invoke(cls, 8)); 
            }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            } 
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            } 
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    }
}
    public int hi(int x) {
        return x;
    }
}
```

The alternate method is to use a large series of if/else or switch/case in conjunction with Scanner reading user input to call all the method names you wish to call.

And just a suggestion for future reference: try some research on your own! I learned a lot just trying to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Scanner`.

For example:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("which calculator you want to use?");

String calculatorType = in.nextLine();

System.out.println("enter first number: ");

String firstNumber = in.nextLine();

System.out.println("enter second number: ");

String secondNumber = in.nextLine();

if(calculatorType.equals("SquareMeter")
    //do something
    System.out.println("Your answer is: " + doSomeCalculation(firstNumber, secondNumber));
```

Inside the if statement you can call a different method depending on what calculation the user asks. In this case that would be the `"SquareMeter"` so the `doSomeCalculation()` would look something like that:

```
int doSomeCalculation(int a, int b){
    return a*b;
}
```

Hope this helps